# limiting svchost.exe because of copping internet good or bad?

Tags: windows-7, bandwidth, svchost, netlimiter

I recently came into problem with one of windows's processes called "svchost" I dont know what is used for, but it chops my bandwith to death and increases my ping (i play online)
I recently installed a Network Manager software and limited "svchost" to 1B/s !
I am not experiencing any problem. Is what ive done good ?
Is svchost for windows update? (I mean checking for update regularly? because I have disabled windows update and will never update it.)
Thanks for useful answers.

Comment: SVCHOST is a wrapper for windows services, typically .dll's that can't be executed directly (without the svchost wrapper)  Typically several windows services will be grouped together into one svchost wrapper.  I'm not sure if you mean one svchost is eating all your bandwidth, or if it's trying to restrict bandwidth.

Comment: No, I use NetBalancer (no way). It groups all svchost processes into one and when I apply the limit it goes to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is svchost.exe ?**

**Svchost.exe** is a process on your computer that hosts, or contains, other individual services that Windows uses to perform various functions. For example, Windows Defender uses a service hosted by a svchost.exe process.

Multiple instances of svchost.exe can run on your computer, each instance containing different services. An instance of svchost.exe might host a single service for a program, and another instance might host several services related to Windows. You can use the Task Manager to view the services running under each instance of svchost.exe.

**How to locate the executed service behind svchost.exe**

1- To open the Task Manager, right-click on the taskbar and click Open Task Manager OR press Ctrl+Shift+Esc.

2- Click the Processes tab.

3- Click Show processes from all users. Administrator permission required If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, provide the password or confirmation.

4- Right-click on an instance of svchost.exe, and then click Access Services. Services associated with the process are highlighted on the Services tab.

Now you know what service is behind svchost.